# Query to update the corresponding parent_ids of table if child_ids are matching in table2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called level_1 and level_2.

```
Create table level_1
(
     parent_id int,  
     child_id int, 
     status varchar(10)
);

Create table level_2
(
     child_id int
);
```

Level_1 table:

```
insert into level_1 
values (11, 12, null), (12, 13, null), (13, 15, null),
       (17, 19, null), (22, 34, null), (23, 22, null),
       (29, 40, null), (40, 55, null), (32, 22, null),
       (19, 22, null), (55, 60, null)
```

Level_2 table:

```
insert into level_2 
values(15), (22), (34), (60)

select * from level_1;

 PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID STATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
        11         12
        12         13
        13         15
        17         19
        22         32
        19         22
        19         40
        40         19
        32         22
        19         22
        55         60
```

11 rows selected.

```
SQL> select * from level_2;

  CHILD_ID
----------
        15
        19
        22
        60
```

Here I should update the status as 'Y' when level_2.child_id=level_1.child_id in Level_1 table and should update the corresponding parent_id values as 'Y' as shown below.

```
    -----------+----------+--------
    parent_id    child_id   status
    -----------+----------+--------
    11             12          Y
    12             13          Y
    13             15          Y
    23             22          Y
    17             19          Y
    19             22          Y
    22             34          Y
    29             40          Y
    40             55          Y
    55             60          Y
    -----------+----------+--------
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you looking to set all the `status`s to `'Y'`?  Are you looking for a recursive query?  Your explanation and your results don't quite match.

Comment: yes lookng for recursive query to update the status column if level_2.child_id=level_1.child_id in Level_1 table and should update the corresponding childids with parent_ids in level_1 table to  'Y' as shown...

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you need recursion here? It sounds like an inner join to me or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: my query:-not working properly..
select a.parent_id, a.child_id ,b.child_id ,
case when a.child_id=b.child_id then 'Y'
when a.child_id=a.parent_id then 'Y' end "Status_update" from level_1 a,level_2 b where a.child_id=b.child_id

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this should be the answer:

```
UPDATE l1
SET status = 'Y'
FROM level_1 l1
    INNER JOIN level_2 l2 ON l1.child_id = l2.child_id;
```

However, there seems to be perhaps an issue with the design of the database.

Comment: here update should happen when child _id is matching with parent_id also it should update corresponding parent_id records with child_id records which are in zigzag manner....

Comment: in oracle hierrachial functions we can use....in mssql am new learner unable to find out which function i have to use